# Security concerns for Ajax using chrome inspect

Tags: ajax, security

I am making one website in which the form is submitted using jQuery ajax. I have taken care of most of the security majors like HTTPS, session cookie, encryption etc.

Hence I have minimised the possibility of outside person sniffing or modify my data transfer.

But there can be a valid registered user who wants to play havoc by using Chrome inspect element. He can for example create a for loop in which is calls my jQuery ajax post call.

Can this be possible? How can I avoid this? I am unable to find a better alternative & resort once again to basic form post instead of ajax.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Anything you present client side can be messed with. A user will always be able to modify your front end code, and do what they want with it. This is why you need server side validation.

If you are worried about a repeating post call, it sounds like you are worried about a DOS attack I guess?

Your server configuration should be set up to detect frequent requests from the same user and deny service to it.

Comment: Hello Thanks for replying Yes I am worried about DOS attack. But if this is so then the premises of Ajax is not safe isn't it? I am using ASP.NET MVC 2 so I hope it has something to detect DOS

Comment: It's not that ajax isn't safe. Ajax is all client side technology. It doesn't matter if its ajax, Curl, or any other method of posting http requests. Inherently, having code execute on the client side should not be trusted on your back end. A user could always use a tool to intercept outgoing packets and modify them accordingly. What I'm trying to say is, any input that you WANT your client to enter from the browser can't be guarenteed. I suggest you look at how to handle DOS by reading up this link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc750213.aspx